# Can you soak a keyboard in distilled water or 99% iso for smells?

Tags: keyboard, cleaning

A slight varient on a somewhat common issuue, but in this case I have a g915 that a cat peed into pretty substantially. The owner then ran the keyboard under the sink and rice dried. While it works fine, it reeks of urine and rice powder.  Do you think I couuld solve this issue for them via soaking the keyboard in either distilled water or iso 99 with it powered off (switch and when battery is drained).  While I believe it should be safe, I am not sure if it's the best way to handle bio smells on hardware like this.

Comment: Have you tried removing the keycaps and washing them? With any luck, that is where the smell is remaining - up under the caps. If you end up soaking it in distilled water, you would have had to take them off anyway to dry it thoroughly. You would want to remove the battery, not drain it - search for videos of "g915 disassembly".

Comment: I doubt soaking is enough here. I think disassembly and manually scrubbing every little corner is required to get rid of all contamination.

Comment: Might be simpler to give the keyboard to the cat and buy another.

Comment: I'll start with keycaps and go from there. Otherwise yeah maybe remove battery, thouugh I am hoping to avoid that. If sodering is involved Im as good as ruined.